# Find published subgraph in rinkeby testnet from the Graph explorer

Tags: blockchain, thegraph

I have published my NFT contract on `Rinkeby testnet` and built, deployed, and published a `subgraph` in the `graph network` for `Rinkeby` network:
[image: subgraph]

But I can't seem to find the `subgraph` on the [Graph Explorer](https://thegraph.com/explorer/). How can I access the `subgraph` from the explorer?

Answer (score 0):

For subgraphs indexing Rinkeby, there's a free `development query url` in The Graph studio you can use for testing. If you publish it to the network, you can't query it because it won't be indexed.